# Coding finite sets in abelian groups

Tags: model-theory

Let $(G,\cdot, e)$ be an abelian group and let $T=Th(G,\cdot, e)$. I wonder if $T$ codes finite sets, that is:
Let $U$ be the monster model of T. Given $X= \{x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\}$ there is some $d \in G$ such that for any automorphism $\sigma$, $\sigma(X)=X$ if and only if $\sigma(d)=d$.

Comment: By "$\sigma(X)=X$" do you mean that $\sigma$ fixes $X$ pointwise, or just that $\{\sigma(x): x\in X\}=X$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\sigma(X) = X$ means $\sigma$ fixes $X$ setwise. And $d\in G$ actually means $d\in G^k$ ($d$ can be a tuple from $G$). The point of "coding finite sets" is to replace a finite (unordered) set with a finite (ordered) tuple so that an automorphism fixes the set (but maybe permutes its elements) if and only if it fixes the tuple (preserving the order of its elements).

Comment: @NoahSchweber This fits into the larger story of "elimination of imaginaries". To say that a theory eliminates imaginaries is to say that for every definable equivalence relation $E$ on $M^n$, there is a definable function $f\colon M^n\to M^k$ for some $k$ realizing the quotient, so $aEb$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$. Now every theory admits the $=$-definable equivalence relations "same set of size $n$", i.e. $(a_1,\dots,a_n)E(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ if and only if $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} = \{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$. A theory codes finite sets if and only if these imaginaries are eliminated.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Interestingly, many theories fail to eliminate imaginaries, but only because they fail to code finite sets. That is (speaking roughly), the category of definable sets has definable "finite set valued" quotients, but not "finite tuple valued" quotients. This is made precise by the notion of "weak elimination of imaginaries": a theory has elimination of imaginaries if and only if it has weak elimination of imaginaries and codes finite sets. Ok, babbling about context over!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always. For example, let $p$ be prime and let $G$ be an abelian group of exponent $p$ (so we can view $G$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$). Let $v,w\in G$ be linearly independent, and let $V = \text{Span}(v,w)$, a $2$-dimensional subspace of $G$ with basis $\{v,w\}$. If $d\in G^n$ codes the pair $\{v,w\}$, then each component $d_i\in \text{dcl}(v,w) = V$. But the map swapping $v$ and $w$ extends to an automorphism of $G$ which fixes the pair $\{v,w\}$ and hence fixes each component $d_i$. So $d_i$ is a vector $(a,a)$ in $\{v,w\}$-coordinates, i.e. $d_i = av + aw\in \text{Span}(v+w)$. But $v\notin \text{Span}(v+w)$, so there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ which fixes $v+w$ and such that $\sigma(v)\neq v$ and $\sigma(v)\neq w$. This automorphism does not fix the pair $\{v,w\}$, but it does fix $d$, contradiction.

The argument above was easy because of the extreme homogeneity provided by linear algebra. It could be that some less homogeneous abelian groups do manage to code finite sets - I'm not sure.